# Difficulty with the use of texture atlases

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having difficulty with the use of texture atlases.
In the picture below the two copies of a model: top with texture atlas. Lower model - with the original texture.
The inspector (right part of the window) active material with the frame of the texture atlas. As you can see, the material uses the correct tile. But this did not prevent UNITY do scan the whole atlas, not only the selected frame (tile).
Why is the "top" model looks like? How to correct this misunderstanding? This is a bug or a feature?

I am sorry for the machine translation from the native language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UV mapping of your object could not work with texture atlas.

For use texture atlas you need a special mesh that use correct uv-mapping.